# iframe API seems to only work on older vanity URLS

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I have searched high and low and am unable to find a solution. It appears to me that the iframe API only works on older style URLs and not the newer customs ones.

What I mean is if a person has a YouTube URL of www.youtube.com/user/THEIR_NAME the iframe API works perfectly. However if they have www.youtube.com/c/THEIR_NAME the iframe API doesn't work.

Specifically I should say that individual video's work fine across all types - mostly because an individual video you add in the ID type for the specific video.

Examples of what I mean, if you add this (note I'll use a well known YouTuber with the older style URL). This works perfectly, the code is designed to find and display the latest uploaded video by the user using the listType=user_uploads and  the list-USERNAME

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?autoplay=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=pewdiepie" frameborder="0"/>
```

The above work exactly as I hoped. Now when I try it on a user that has the newer vanity URL of youtube.com/c/USERNAME I get a black screen in place of the video and on pressing the play button it says "An error occurred please try again later". This happens regardless of who I put in the list= field. If they have the new style /c/USERNAME address the video won't show up. Individual videos will show up from that user if listed though.

Example, same code as above but with a user that has the newer /c/USERNAME URL.

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?autoplay=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=poziix" frameborder="0"/>
```

From the same user if I did the following code (below) it displays the video perfectly and as expected, again because it's using the video ID instead of the user channel name.

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/HMP35vpPn6w?autoplay=0&showinfo=0&rel=0" frameborder="0"/>
```

I have tried this with a number of users that have the newer vanity URL of /c/USERNAME. I have also tried to use the actual name instead of the vanity for example I tried replacing "poziix" with "UCU0E_r2fyLxDQhhdLYcJrNA" the actual name and again no luck. I have also tried the name and actual name of another user with the /c/USERNAME with no luck.

Can someone advise on how I can go about fixing this? I am making a web site that is to display the latest uploaded video as it changes, and to date I've running into a brick wall.

Thank you kindly in advance.

Comment: Did I put this in the wrong area or not press the right button to have people read it? I still have the problem and would really love some help in fixing it. if this is in the wrong area, can someone let me know so I can put it in an area where people answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Was having this exact same issue with the exact same use scenario.

Here's what I found... Go to the user's channel, all uploads, and then take the section of the url after '/channel/' which from what I can tell always starts with 'UC' on the newer channels. Use this, and change the first two letters from 'UC' to 'UU'

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=[UU.....]
```

I can't find any mention of `videoseries`on the iFrame Player API.